# Переполнение буфера, затирание данных в стеке и SegFault

Tags: c, ассемблер

Есть такая программа с переполняющимися буферами:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];

    strcpy(buffer_one, "one"); /* put "one" into buffer_one */
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two"); /* put "two" into buffer_two */

    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);

    printf("\n[STRCPY] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n",  strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]); /* copy first argument into buffer_two */

    printf("[AFTER] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
}
```

Будем передавать на вход строки разной длины, при этом данные в стеке постепенно затираются. Вот момент до того, как еще не случился сегфолт:

```
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0xbfd7af0c and contains 'two'
[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0xbfd7af14 and contains 'one'
[BEFORE] value is at 0xbfd7af1c and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY] copying 19 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0xbfd7af0c and contains 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0xbfd7af14 and contains 'AAAAAAAAAAA'
[AFTER] value is at 0xbfd7af1c and is 4276545 (0x00414141)
```

Видно, что локальная переменная value постепенно заполняется кодами буквы `A`: (0x00414141). Данные располгаются в таком порядке, как это видно по адресам и дампу `GDB`: `buffer_two`, `buffer_one`, `value`.

Почему произошел сегфолт после передачи строки на единицу длиннее предыдущей?

```
[STRCPY] copying 20 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0xbfd69d8c and contains 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB'
[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0xbfd69d94 and contains 'AAAAAAAAAAAB'
[AFTER] value is at 0xbfd69d9c and is 1111572801 (0x42414141)
Segmentation fault
```

Я же просто до конца заполнил переменную `value` буквами `AAAB`, и никакого выхода за границы сегмента не произошло.

Comment: А вы не забыли, что strcpy _ВСЕГДА_ записывает в конец строки двоичный ноль, что бы был собственно конец строки. И когда вы копируете 20 байт он пишет 21

Comment: Да, действительно, дописывается ноль. А где тогда границы стека для этой программы?  Почему нельзя перезаписывать то, что находится в стеке ниже?

Comment: а там лежит адрес возврата из функции и ret переходит уже не туда кто вызывал ,main и должен завершить корректно работу программы

Comment: Разве там именно адрес возврата?  RET сохраняется перед вызовом функции, а потом функция кладет на стек  EBP.

Comment: Ну так вы ассемблерный код функции привели бы. Я же не знаю, что ваш компилятор там еще делает со стеком. Хотя разрушение  EBP вызывающей функции то же ни к чему хорошему не приведет

Comment: Вот дизасс другой функции main: http://pastebin.com/yRd0PmC5 GCC делает пролог функции и сохраняет ebp.

Comment: Полный дамп функции из ОП-поста: http://pastebin.com/6YzFGhYY

Comment: Есть какие-нибудь мануалы по отладке таких критических ситуаций в GDB? Я пока что плохо умею им пользоваться, а хочется самому исследовать, что происходит с программой. Гуглится только совсем простое: https://habrahabr.ru/post/181738/

Answer (score 3):

Вы использовали копирование строки с помощью `strcpy`, а строка - это еще и нулевой завершающий байт. Вот он-то и портит вам всю музыку :)